# Error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function C++ at outfile.close

Tags: c++

The error occurs at outFile.close;
Not sure why it does that but I would love some help.  Thanks!
I'm sort of new to c++ so it could probably be something very simple that I've overlooked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
void what1();

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
void what1()
{
    int counter=20;
    float num1=rand();
    fstream infile;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("randomdata.txt");
    if (!outFile)
    {
        cout << "File not open";
    }
    else
    {
        while (counter<=20)
        {
            num1=rand();
            outFile<<num1<<endl;
            counter++;
        }
        outFile<<num1;
        outFile.close;
    }
}
```

Comment: `outFile.close()`

Comment: thank you!  That fixed my problem.

Comment: Even simpler: don't bother calling `outfile.close()`. The destructor will do that.